# Finding the limit of $ (1-\ln^{n+1}\lvert x\rvert)/(1-\ln\lvert x\rvert)$, as $n$ tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

The problem is like this: it asks to find the set of values of the function $$
f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-\ln^{n+1}\lvert x\rvert}{1-\ln\lvert x\rvert} \qquad (x\ne0)
$$
Now, what I've tried is to give some values to $x$ and it seems like for $x=1$ the limit equals $1$, for $x>1$ the limit equals infinity. I've also tried doing a graph for it and it seems like the set of values for the function is $[1,\infty)$. I was looking to see a exact method (step-by-step). I've also attached a picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the problem should also state $\ln\lvert x\rvert\ne1$, that is, $x\ne\pm e$.

You can leave out the logarithm and consider instead
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-t^n}{1-t}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{t^n-1}{t-1}
$$
where $t=\ln\lvert x\rvert$ and $t\ne1$.

Think to what you know about
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}t^n
$$

1. For $t>1$, the limit is…
2. For $-1<t<1$, the limit is…
3. For $t\le -1$, the limit…

After you have filled in the dots, you will know the answer in terms of $t$ and you can then pass to $x$, because $|x|=e^t$.

Answer (score 2):

We obtain the answer immediately:

For $|x|>e$ it goes to $+\infty$.

For $\frac{1}{e}<|x|<e$  it's closed to $$\frac{1}{1-\ln|x|}.$$
For $0<|x|\leq\frac{1}{e}$ the limit does not exist.

Comment: Your answer is not completely correct. One has to consider $0<|x|<1/e$, $|x|=1/e$ and $1/e <|x|<e$ separately.

Comment: @Gary Thank you! I fixed.